# Combine text from multiple cells into a single cell forming a sentence?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to combine text from Cell A2, B2, C2-I2, J2, into a sentence in E2.
Same thing would continue down in Row 3, 4, 5, etc.
I would want the sentence to end up being "[A2] can be bought from [B2], by [C2-I2] after you do the quest: "[J2]"."
C2-I2 each cell may or may not have a name. If it has a name, it should be included with a comma. If not, it should be left out. I can add the comma in-cell if it makes it easier.

Here is an example
[image: Example pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
=A2&" can be bought from "&B2&" by: "&join(", ",filter(C2:I2,len(C2:I2)))&", after completing the quest """&J2&""""
```

The operator `&` is concatenation; its effect is identical to `concatenate` formula, but I find `&` easier to type.

```
join(", ",filter(C2:I2,len(C2:I2)))
```

takes only the nonempty cells in the range C2:I2 and joins them, separating by comma and space. I am assuming at least one cell in this range is nonempty, otherwise the sentence won't make much sense no matter what.

The   contraption `..."""&J2&""""` at the end is escaping quote marks within a string. To be escaped, `"` must be repeated. So, `""""` is the string containing one character, namely `"`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your informative and expedient response. Many internet cookies for you!